# Copy section of data string from one column to another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace, sql-update

Table and (columns) in question are:

Attachment (att_name and att_path)

I make this call to Select the info I want to update:

```
select * from attachment
where att_path like '%//bahamas/attachments/images/logos/%'
```

I need to update the att_name column with the filename in the path above. For example, if SQL finds "//bahamas/attachments/images/logos/**ABCDE.tif**" I need SQL to update the att_name to replace whatever is currently in there and insert **ABCDE.tif**

I have tried multiple different test's on just one item and I can't seem to get my SQL correct to implement a global call where this update runs on all rows where att_path like '%//bahamas/attachments/images/logos/%'

Any advise/help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update attachment set
       att_name = Right(att_path, CharIndex('/', Reverse(att_path)) - 1)
 where att_path like '%//bahamas/attachments/images/logos/%'
```

should do what you want.
Reversing and then searching the first occurrence of `/` in effect searches from the end.

Before running the update, however, I usually run a select to check if I hit the correct character positions when developing statements like the following, as it is easy to get [off-by-one errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) with string manipulations:

```
select att_path, Right(att_path, CharIndex('/', Reverse(att_path)) - 1)
  from attachment
 where att_path like '%//bahamas/attachments/images/logos/%'
```

Comment: The update worked great! Thanks for showing me the logic behind this, I will note for the future. I was unable to get the Select statement to work though, I'm assuming because it needs to know which table to pull from...

Comment: @MattWeick You are completely right! I added the from clause.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!